# Java Program Compiles and Runs, but doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, awt

When I run this program I enter information in a text box, push the search button, but nothing happens. The program just sits there until I press Cntrl C to break it. It looks like it should work, but I can't figure out what is hanging the program up.

Here is the code:
First class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class NameGameFrame extends JFrame
{
    public static String name;
    static JTextField textfield = new JTextField(20);
    static JTextArea  textarea = new JTextArea(30,30);
    public static String num;
    public static String [] fields;
    public static int [] yearRank;
    public static boolean match;
    public static int getInts, marker, year, max;

    public static void main( String[] args)
    {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Name Game");
        frame.setLocation(500,400);
        frame.setSize(800,800);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter the Name or Partial Name to search:");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.insets = new Insets(2,2,2,2);

        panel.add(label,c);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(textarea,c);

        JButton button = new JButton("Search");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(button,c);

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(textfield,c);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                name = textfield.getText();
                java.io.File file = new java.io.File("namesdata.txt");
                try
                {
                    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
                    num = input.nextLine();
                    NameRecord nr = new NameRecord(name);
                    while (input.hasNext())
                    {

                        if(match = num.toLowerCase().contains(name.toLowerCase()))
                        {
                            nr.getRank();
                            nr.getBestYear(marker);
                        } 
                    }
                }
                catch(FileNotFoundException e)
                {
                    System.err.format("File does not exist\n");
                }
                textarea.setText(fields[0]);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

This is the second class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class NameRecord
{

    public NameRecord( String name)
    {

    }

    public static int getBestYear(int marker)
    {
        switch (marker)
        {
            case 1:
                year = 1900;
                break;
            case 2:
                year = 1910;
                break;
            case 3:
                year = 1920;
                break;
            case 4:
                year = 1930;
                break;            
            case 5:
                year = 1940;
                break;
            case 6:
                year = 1950;
                break;
            case 7:
                year = 1960;
                break;
            case 8:
                year = 1970;
                break;    
            case 9:
                year = 1980;
                break;
            case 10:
                year = 1990;
                break;
            case 11:
                year = 2000;
                break;
        }
        return year;                    
    }

    public static int getRank()
    {
        fields = num.split(" ");
        max = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i<12; i++)
        {   
            getInts = Integer.parseInt(fields[i]);
            if(getInts>max)
            {
                max = getInts;
                marker = i;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Richard, consider using a debugger to debug your code and trace its execution. At best, you may find the answer yourself, at worst, it will at least give you some more information to post here that will help make the question more specific.

Comment: Do you ever assign something to the `fields[]` array?

Comment: Awful, ugly code.  getBestYear would be a small method if you put that into a Map and simply did a lookup using marker as the key and year as the value.

Comment: Why did you delete the code in your question? I've un-deleted it for you.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you have a loop on the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) that may not complete due to calling `hasNext()` instead of `hasNextLine()`, when using the `nextLine()` result (see `button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()`).

Irrespectively, you should to invoke a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) or such to create a thread to do the processing that takes a long time, then use the EDT to display the result. It will make future issues easier to debug, as well as being the proper thing to do.